# Android Studio is generating very old apk for react-native project like 3 months old

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Android Studio is generating very old apk for react-native project like 3 months old. But running perfectly in emulator while running this command "react-native run-android"

Process -
* Open file location
* Build => Build Bundles => Build APK

Tried re-installing android studio but still getting old APK

Comment: this is because the bundle the android platform uses is old

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the old react-native version, when we generate the android APK, sometimes the bundle is old, we have to generate it by ourself.
In the react-native 0.61, I find the problem is dismissed.
In the old version, firstly you should add the following script to the package.json

```
"scripts":{
...
"bundle-android": "react-native bundle --entry-file index.js  --platform android --dev false --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res",
...
}
```

the when you generate the apk , you firstly run the follwing script in the termail to generate the new bundle

```
npm run bundle-android
```

when the bundle outputs successfully, then go into the android directory and assemble the APK

```
cd android

./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because, you have old index.android.bundle file. Follow these steps to update this file and create a new apk:

1. `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
2. `curl "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android" -o "android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle"`
3. `cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleDebug`

Answer (score 1):

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js -- 
bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest 
android/app/src/main/res/
```

If you get an error of duplicate resources than go to res folder and delete the drawable-hdpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-xhdpi,drawable-xxhdpi,drawable-xxxhdpi folder only and try to rebuild the project. It will work.