# React Native Android runs in dev but not with release

Tags: android, react-native

I get these logs and don't understand what it is I need to do. The app has worked for months testing, now I am finally ready to release and it crashes immediately upon opening!  I do not understand these logs but maybe someone can see something I can't? I ran `react-native run-android --variant=release` then I ran this `adb logcat "*:E"`, then I open the app and this is what I get...

```
11-08 15:56:03.535 29663 29663 E com.myapp: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
11-08 15:56:03.584   549  3978 E msm8916_platform: platform_check_backends_match: Invalid snd_device =
11-08 15:56:03.586  1075  1134 E PRM_CONFIG_Parser: get_custom_config not found
11-08 15:56:03.592   549  3978 E ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB_CMD_GET_AFE_COMMON_TABLE_SIZE Returned = -19
11-08 15:56:03.729  1075  1134 E PRM_CONFIG_Parser: get_custom_config not found
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: create_react_context
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp, PID: 29663
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a Metro server (run 'react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets(Native Method)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:218)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript(JSBundleLoader.java:31)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:247)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1152)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900(ReactInstanceManager.java:123)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:943)
11-08 15:56:04.183 29663 29691 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
11-08 15:56:04.259  1075  1134 E PRM_CONFIG_Parser: get_custom_config not found
11-08 15:56:04.652  1893  2092 E InputDispatcher: channel 'e1bed86 com.myapp/com.myapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
11-08 15:56:04.714 12294 12356 E chromium: [ERROR:aw_gl_functor.cc(102)] Received unexpected kModeProcessNoContext
11-08 15:56:04.717 12294 12356 E chromium: [ERROR:aw_gl_functor.cc(102)] Received unexpected kModeProcessNoContext
11-08 15:56:07.734  1893  2396 E TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

Comment: the situation is the same as this question(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58704073/android-studio-is-generating-very-old-apk-for-react-native-project-like-3-months/58704525#58704525), you can try to do it firstly

Comment: Thanks @Lenoarod, that, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52632950/react-native-0-57-1-android-duplicate-resources) was what I needed.